# Regex string parsing: pattern starts with ; but can end with [;,)%&@]

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, python-re

I am attempting to parse strings using Regex. The strings look like:

```
Stack;O&verflow;i%s;the;best!
```

I want to parse it to:

```
Stack&verflow%sbest!
```

So when we see a `;` remove everything up until we see one of the following characters: [;,)%&@] (or replace with empty space "").

I am using `re` package in Python:

```py
string = re.sub('^[^-].*[)/]$', '', string)
```

This is what I have right now:

```
^[^;].*[;,)%&@]
```

Which as I understand it says: starting at the pattern with `;`, read everything that matches in between `;` and [;,)%&@] characters

But the result is wrong and looks like:

```
Stack;O&verflow;i%s;the;
```

[Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/RH7czE/1)

What am I missing?

EDIT: @InSync pointed out that there is a discrepancy if `;` is in the end characters as well. As worded above, it should result in`Stack&verflow%s**;**best!` but instead I want to see `Stack&verflow%sbest!`. Perhaps two regex lines are appropriate here, I am not sure; if you can get to `Stack&verflow%s**;**best!` then the rest is just simple replacement of all the remaining `;`.

EDIT2: The code I found that works was

```
import re

def remove_semicolons(name):
    name = re.sub(';.*?(?=[;,)%&@])', '', name)
    name = re.sub(';','',name)
    return name

remove_semicolons('Stack;O&verflow;i%s;the;best!')
```

Or if you feel like causing a headache to the next programmer who looks at your code:

```
import re

semicolon_string = 'Stack;O&verflow;i%s;the;best!'

cleaned_string = re.sub(';','',re.sub(';.*?(?=[;,)%&@])', '', semicolon_string))
```

Comment: In your expected result, `;O&` was replaced with `&` and `;i%` with `%` but `;the;` was replaced with nothing. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: [;].*?(?=[;,)%&@])

Comment: @OmOWalker If you have an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: What should be the output for `;A;B;`? As it is, `;` can act as both a start and an end character, which creates some ambiguity. Thus, if overlapping matches ***are*** allowed, the correct output would be `;` - but if not, the correct output would be `;B;`.

Comment: @InSync,thank you for pointing this out; I did not see this until now but there has to be 2 separate regex here. The expected result is right; the discrepancy is because the end result should have no `;` in it, whereas the other end characters should still be left in there. I will edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: @ekhumoro, for `;A;B;`, ideally the result should be `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright in my answer I assume you have a typo in your expected output. Remove everything starting with ; up to (;,)%&@) and so

Stack **;O** &verflow **;i** %s **;the** ;best!

would become

Stack&verflow%s;best!

for the regex you want to start with `;` then anything after 0 or more times `.*` (if you require a character change to `.+`) followed by your ending characters `[;,)%&@]`. To exclude them you need to add a positive lookahead `?(?=[;,)%&@])`. This as the name suggests looks ahead one character and tries to match it to your sequence

For a final regex:

```
;.*?(?=[;,)%&@])
```

or if you require characters in between:

```
;.+?(?=[;,)%&@])
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I didn't realize there was a discrepancy; I did want the remaining semicolons removed, so I added a second regex line to do that.